# Treating Enum as regular property in Class

Tags: java, enums, getter-setter

I have a class consisting of several properties, one of them is an `enum`:

```
public class Car {

    private String manufacturer;
    private int power;

    public enum Color {
        RED("red"),
        BLUE("blue"),
        GREEN("green");

        private final String value;

        Color(final String value) {
            this.value = value;
        }

        public String getValue() {
            return value;
        }
    }

    public String getManufacturer() {
        return manufacturer;
    }

    public void setManufacturer(String manufacturer) {
        this.manufacturer = manufacturer;
    }

    public int getPower() {
        return power;
    }

    public void setPower(int power) {
        this.power = power;
    }

    public Car(String manufacturer, int power, Color color) {
        this.manufacturer = manufacturer;
        this.power = power;
//        Color(color); // Calling constructor, but --> ERROR: cannot find symbol
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Car{" + "manufacturer=" + manufacturer + ", power=" + power + '}'; // TODO add color
    }

}
```

I put that class into a list and populate it with some values:

```
List<Car>  car = Arrays.asList(
          new Car("Mazda", 95, Car.Color.BLUE),
          new Car("Toyota", 110, Car.Color.RED),
          new Car("Honda", 85, Car.Color.GREEN)
  );
```

Want I want is to use that class like a regular DTO, with its getters and setters:

```
System.out.println(car.get(0));
```

But int my case I only get:

```
Car{manufacturer=Mazda, power=95}
```

So the `color` attribute is missing.

How can I use the `enum` type as a regular property of my class?

Comment: What's stopping you from adding your `enum` to the `toString()` method?

Comment: @Zephyr: How do I access its value? Simply `Color.getValue()` doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use enum type like any other type in java. Just try:

```
private String manufacturer;
private int power;
private Color color;  // here is the property of enum type

....

public Car(String manufacturer, int power, Color color) {
    this.manufacturer = manufacturer;
    this.power = power;
    this.color = color;
}

Car newCar = new Car("manufacturer", 150, Color.RED);
```

Comment: So I would need to create an own class just for my enum `Color`? Could I just keep it as an inner class?

Comment: @user1170330 you could keep it as inner class

Comment: No. you can leave your Color enum definition where it is.

Comment: Thank you! I didn't know I can just do `Color color`, like with a regular class.

Answer (score 0):

I would personally have the enum in its own file (just for readability) and have an enum as a member variable in your class car.

then in your enum file put a toString function like this

```
   public String toString()
   {
        String returnValue = "";

        switch (this)
        {
           case RED:
            returnValue = "Red";
            break;
           case BLUE:
            returnValue = "Blue";
            break;
        }

        return returnValue;
    }
```

Then in your toString for the car do:

```
return "Car{" + "manufacturer=" + manufacturer + ", power=" + power + " Colour = " + colour.toString() + "}";
```

with colour been a member variable of the enum in this class.